# SQL Server / EF - Database Design

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm currently going to begin a new project to help with Complaints. I have worked out all the fields etc.. but in doing so, I've realised I need more than 1 type of Complaint. They are Customer Complaint, Supplier Complaint or Defect Complaint. They share many of the same fields but differ slightly, so I'm not sure how I would design this in a SQL Server database and/or using EF. The application will be an ASP.NET MVC 4 application using C#, so I could take advantage of Code First but as I said, I'm not sure how I'd design these Entities:

All 3 complaint types share the following columns:

```
ComplaintType (int), Department (int), 
Code (int), DefectReference (string), Cause (int)
```

Customer complaint and supplier complaint share these columns:

```
ComplaintText (string), Orders (collection), Rectification (string)
```

Here are columns unique to customer complaint:

```
AccountNumber (string), CustomerName (string)
```

And finally, here are fields unique to Supplier Complaint:

```
SupplierNumber (string), SupplierName (string)
```

So my questions are:

1. How would I approach this creating my Models to use with EF Code First or
2. How would I design this using SQL Server?

Thanks

Note: There are more columns (ID's etc..) but I've shortened it for this example.

Comment: That depends on whether you'll model you application from domain objects or databbase tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about implementing inheritance in Code First, and it all depends on how you want the tables represented in SQL.

Do you want a single complaint table for all types, where some fields are left null based on what type it is? You'd use [Table Per Hierarchy](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) for that.

Do you want a main complaint table that house the common fields, and then relational tables which hold the extra columns, based on class?  You'd use [Table per Type](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx) for that.

If you want a single table per complaint type, with the common fields expressed in every table?  That's [Table per Concrete Type](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx)

Personally, with what you have I'd probably lean towards Table Per Type. Here's a shortened example:

```
public abstract class Complaint 
{
    public int ComplaintType { get; set; }
    public int Department { get; set; }
    public int Code  { get; set; }
}

[Table("CustomerComplaint")]
public class BankAccount : Complaint
{
    public string ComplaintText { get; set; }
    public string Rectification { get; set; }
}

[Table("SupplierComplaint")]
public class SupplierComplaint: Complaint
{
    public string SupplierNumber { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thats a great answer! Thanks, I'll look at the different types and see what's best!

Comment: Regarding this, in my DbContext class, do I have to create a DbSet for each Table? So, in your example: `Complaint`, `BankAccount`, `SupplierComplaint`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, generally the EF Code First strategy is the best option.

You should to create a `Complaint` class and to use (delegate) this class into `Supplier`, `Customer` and `Defect` classes. Inheritance hierarchy can harm your design extensibility. Always favor composition over inheritance.

Comment: What do you mean by Composition over Inheritence? Example?